# Matrix involving reciprocal factorials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factorial, toeplitz-matrices, schur-complement

Let $m$ and $n$ be two integers and $m \le n$. There are a matrix $A$ of $m$-by-$m$ with $A(i,j) = 1/(2n+2j-2i)!$  and a vector $r$ of $m$ entries with $r(i) = 2/(2n+2i)!$.

Is there a formula for the inner product of $r$ and the first column of the inverse of $A$?

Or, can it be shown that the inner product aforementioned is bounded from above by a constant strictly less than one?

The background of this question is as follows. There is a linear system
$$
   \begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{2}{(2n+2)!} & \frac{2}{(2n+4)!} & \ldots & \frac{2}{(2n+2m)!} \\1 & \frac{1}{(2n)!} & \frac{1}{(2n+2)!} & \ldots & \frac{1}{(2n+2m-2)!}\\ 0 & \frac{1}{(2n-2)!} & \frac{1}{(2n)!} & \ldots & \frac{1}{(2n+2m-4)!}\\ 0 & \frac{1}{(2n-4)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-2)!} & \ldots & \frac{1}{(2n+2m-6)!}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & \frac{1}{(2n+2-2m)!} & \frac{1}{(2n+4-2m)!} & \ldots & \frac{1}{(2n)!}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}v_0\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}v_1\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}v_2\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}v_3\\ \vdots\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}v_m\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}O(\epsilon)\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}O(\epsilon)\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}}O(\epsilon)\\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}} O(\epsilon) \\ \vdots \\ \vphantom{\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}} O(\epsilon)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It can be found the previous matrix $A$ is just the the bottom right part of the above coefficient matrix, from the 2nd column to the last and from the 2nd row to the last. The previous vector $r$ is just the top right part of the above coefficient matrix, from the 2nd column to the last in the 1st row.

It is wanted to have an estimate of $v_0$. Can it be shown that $v_0=O(\epsilon)$ independent of $m$ and $n$?